# remove index.php of laravel routing

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-routing, laravel-5.6

When I add `index.php` at the end of my domain name(`www.example.com/index.php`) and then click on other routes, the `index.php` add to their URL. But I see on other Laravel websites that even you add `index.php` and then click on other routes, the URL will be:
`www.example.com/ROUTE_NAME` **(I mean `index.php` has gone.)**

How can I achieve this for my website?
I'm using shared hosting(Apache+Nginx) and my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: did you ask it again?

Comment: My previous question was about how can I redirect `index.php` to `/`

Comment: It all depends on how the links you use to other locations are generated. The .htaccess rule (which only Apache uses by the way) does not necessarily strip out the index.php it just rewrites requests that don't include it.

Comment: It depends, do you use apache or nginx? Apache and nginx are two different programs. I'd highly doubt both would be used at the same time to host a single website. Perhaps start with finding out which of the 2 you are using.